# What are the benefits of a zero argument constructor? when is it ideal?

Tags: java

Why would anyone want to define a zero argument constructor when a default parameterless constructor is created during compile time anyway? Are there any benefits to doing so? are there any cases where it is better to define a zero argument constructor within a class for the sole purpose of preventing the default from being created during compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: you define it when you need it.

For example to call another constructor with some default values which are then used by the other constructor to initialize fields of the class.

When you write down an "empty" constructor that does nothing besides calling the super constructor then sure - you wrote useless code that should go away.

Comment: Ah, so its ideal in cases where you might want to access and call constructors from other classes?

Comment: Read my answer - you use it when you have to.

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is added by java internally if user does not define any parametrised constructor. It initialises any uninitialised fields to their default values.
Like `int to 0
string to null
object to null`

Answer (score -3):

It's needed if you want to execute an init-function as soon as a new object of the class is created. For Example:

public class Example {

```
public Example() {
        init();
    } 

    public void init() {
        //do some Stuff
    }
```

}

But Just defining it without doing anything is not sensefull.